# Compiler error with sfinae and custom power function

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I want to implement power of integer in metaprogramming way with sfinae like

```
#include <iostream>

template<bool B, typename T = void> struct enable_if;

template<typename T>
struct enable_if<true, T> { using type = T; };

template<typename T>
struct enable_if<false, T> {};

template<int N, typename T>
typename enable_if <(N == 0), T>::type my_pow(T x) {
    return 1;
};

template<int N, typename T> // block1
typename enable_if <(N > 0) && (N % 2 == 1), T>::type my_pow(T x) {
    return my_pow<N - 1>(x) * x;
};

template<int N, typename T> // block2
typename enable_if <(N > 0) && (N % 2 == 0), T>::type my_pow(T x) {
    T p = my_pow<N / 2>(x);
    return p * p;
};

};

auto y_2_5 = my_pow<2>(5);
//auto y_3_5 = my_pow<3>(5);

int main()
{
    std::cout << y_2_5 << std::endl;
//    std::cout << y_3_5 << std::endl;
}
```

It works for y_2_5, but does not work if uncomment lines with y_3_5. But if you exchange block1 and block2, y_2_5 does not work too.
Maybe, it happens because of some compiler's flag. Is there a possibility to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of declarations matters. Whichever block appears first does not see the other block. Which means that when you do overload resolution in the body of the first block, the second block won't be a candidate. Only declarations that are visible up to that point are candidates (excluding other details like ADL, which don't apply here).

The remedy is pretty straight forward, add declarations of both function templates, before defining them. This way, it doesn't matter which is actually defined first.

```
template<int N, typename T>
typename enable_if <(N > 0) && (N % 2 == 1), T>::type my_pow(T x);

template<int N, typename T>
typename enable_if <(N > 0) && (N % 2 == 0), T>::type my_pow(T x);

template<int N, typename T> // block1
typename enable_if <(N > 0) && (N % 2 == 1), T>::type my_pow(T x) {
    return my_pow<N - 1>(x) * x;
}

template<int N, typename T> // block2
typename enable_if <(N > 0) && (N % 2 == 0), T>::type my_pow(T x) {
    T p = my_pow<N / 2>(x);
    return p * p;
}
```

Comment: This. And if anyone wants to see the official wording: [\[temp.dep.candidate\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep.candidate)